# how to limit visitors to an api end point to those that are visiting my site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

My website does not require login. And actions that the user takes end in calling ASP.NET MVC Controller Action Methods. Any other company can call those endpoints at this time and use my APIs in this way. I want to make sure that only users who are on my site can access these APIs.

How do I achieve that?

Adding clarification:

Say my site is consoto.com.  I want my methods to work only if the end user is on consoto.com.  Now if another company or hacker builds a site say hackland.com and in their javascript calls my methods, I want it to fail because their users are not on consoto.com and instead are on hackLand.com.

Many sites these days offer paid official API access to their core functionality.  If they don't implement a mechanism like this, others will have the option to call the methods the actual site uses instead of going through the paid API.  What would prevent a hackland.com to just use the methods used by consoto.com and end up not paying for the service?

Comment: what do you mean "any other company" and what API? but you could set a cookie or session for your site and check the cookie or session, as your site is the only place that can give that session you have the deal done, but i dont think your website is limited to just companies

Comment: If you do not require clients to log in(or authenticate themselves in some way (i.e. secrete tokens, authorization cookies etc), then how can you reliable differentiate between "users who are on your site" and "other company" in the first place?

Comment: @minus4 I just added a better explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @BojinLi please see my edits in the post. Hopefully I cleared up the confusion. Thanks!

Comment: think your maybe a little paranoid, I only see html on your website and to be thinking yours is the only site on the internet, that has the wonderful output of data is maybe a little nieve to say the least even if you did authentication if this is ajax data, you can simply save with multiple tools.  if you do have something that is amazing then maybe you should NOT supply the data to the public

Answer (score 0):

I'm not %100 sure I understand you but, it seems like you only want to give active users on your website the ability to call certain action methods. If that is the case you can decorate the action methods with `[ChildActionOnly]`. This will force ASP to only allow actions that are called with `HTML.Action()` in the view code.

controller code

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult someAction()
{
    //return whatever you need
}
```

view code

```
Html.Action("someAction")
```

That should prevent people that aren't actively viewing the site from calling an action on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reliable way to achieve that if you don't require authentication on your site a then allow only authenticated users to call server side actions.

Comment: Thanks! This should be a common enough problem.  Look at stack overflow. (or for that matter Google itself). They do not require login. So I can build a site that basically calls their controller methods and wala, I have much of their functionality on my site. Would I just limit the number of hits from any particular ip per hour?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use some sort of time sensitive token that the client must supply to your Controller.

1. Implement a web service that takes some credentials from the user, and if the credentials are valid, return a time sensitive token that is hashed based on your server clock.  This service should be called through SSL so the credentials are protected in transit.
2. Each of your protected controllers will expect this token in addition to whatever other inputs they currently expect.  You will then validate the token by de-hashing it to obtain the time stored within.  Here you can decide how long you want the token to be valid for and choose a time interval to accept.  For tokens that do not de-hash property or are expired, return some error result.  For tokens that are valid, return the correct result.  Rather than the tokens being time sensitive, you can also implement a use count scenario, but the time sensitive approach is easier.

This way, your API controllers will not require login or SSL.  Your valid users will just need to obtain the token from you before hand and then use it to call your services.  Anyone else can intercept these tokens but they won't be any good after a possibly very short period of time.